# Тип устройства в windows. Системное программирование

Tags: windows, wmi

Получаю список устройств 2-умя способами.

- Через WMI: Win32_PnPEntity
- Черeз Cfgmgr.dll

И там и там есть свойство:

- PnPClass
- CM_DRP_CLASS

соответственно.

Список типов устройств одинаковый:

- SoftwareDevice
- System
- Volume
- Battery
- DiskDrive
- USB
- PrintQueue
- Bluetooth
- Net
- HIDClass
- Image
- Mouse
- AudioEndpoint
- SCSIAdapter
- MTD
- VolumeSnapshot
- Display
- Computer
- Keyboard
- MEDIA
- Processor
- Sensor
- CDROM
- hdc
- Monitor

---

Проблема в том, что я нигде не нашел это перечисление. Является ли оно стандартом для всех систем Windows? Т.е. могу ли я основываясь на этот список, делить устройства на функциональные группы на разных компьютерах под управлением ОС Windows? Или есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш список неполный. На сайте Microsoft есть статья "System-Defined Device Setup Classes" (пишу название, потому, что  Microsoft может в очередной раз поменять ссылки у себя на сайте).

Полный список можно составить исходя из [этого](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и [этого](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Обратите внимание, названия в вашем списке это строки напротив Class = {Название класса}

Единственное, чего не пойму, откуда берется SoftwareDevice.

Comment: Спасибо.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957340.aspx
Я так понимаю SoftwareDevice не является классом, зарезервированным системой.

Comment: @CheslavBochko Ну да. Логично.